# Getting Your Customer's Bills in to Bill Pay Sites

Tags: language-agnostic, billing, payment

We are looking at ways to cut costs, and one idea I had was to push our customer's bills into the Bill Pay systems that banks (and other sites) use. Only thing is, I don't know how to do that? My searches in the past didn't turn up any information for the company side.

Can anyone point me in a productive direction? Is there a single clearing house for this or do you have to set something up with each site?

**More details:** We are a local government that sends out utility bills on a monthly basis. We currently offer ACH and online bill payment (through our web site) options. But with so many (or so it seems) people using the free bill pay that banks are now offering, it would be a great option to push their bills to those that like to use this option. If it's cost effective, that is.

Comment: Do you have any more information? What industry? How frequent are the bills? Could you build your own system to send out a PDF bill and then let them pay online through your website etc?

Comment: I don't know how these are done either, but I bet if you talked to one of your local banks or credit unions (who receive electronic billing for their customers), they could help you connect with the right people.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest contacting a bank. The banks that I have accounts at let me set it up by adding the name, address, and account number. They don't have a list of approved vendors.

Good luck! I work for a local government and am currently working on an online system to view and pay utility bills.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pushing them to a third party (who you presumably pay for the service) could you build your own system?

Either email a PDF bill, or let them log onto your website to get their balance etc. Then let them pay through your website?

It's not that difficult to sent up an online payment system....

Comment: We already offer ACH and a way to pay with a credit card through our website.

Comment: I should also mention that there is nothing preventing a person from adding their bill to the bill pay system. Which currently sends us a check. This, however, causes extra work for the bill processors. We are looking for ways to save them time (thus save us money). 

We are contacting the bank on this. I'll update once I know what exactly needs to be done for future people to look at.